# R markdown how do I conditionally set the font color within inline code

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following line of code in an R markdown document.
The variables uplift_all and bench are determined beforehand.
This line is supposed to test if uplift_all is larger than bench and if so I want to display the value of uplift_all in green font, if not I want it in red font.
Can anyone suggest how I would amend the code so that the font colors are displayed as desired?

```
<font size="15">***`r if(uplift_all > bench){ uplift_all} else{ uplift_all}` %***</font>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a convenient function to set a font color:

```
textcolor <- function(text, color){
  sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", color, text)
}
```

Then do

```
`r textcolor(uplift_all, ifelse(uplift_all > bench, "green", "red"))`
```